# Display color as option description in ckeditor dialog select field

Tags: javascript, dialog, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have created a custom CKEditor dialog with a select list field that allows the users to select from a predefined list of 5 hex color values (so I don't want/need a full blown color picker) that are used in the HTML that is inserted in the onOk function. For now, I'm using a text description of the color values, like so:

```
  {
    type: 'select',
    id: 'donateButtonColor',
    label: 'Select the button background color',
    items: [['Mustard', 'C9920E'], ['Dark Blue', '002F87'], ['Green', '4A7628'], ['Orange', 'EE7624'], ['Light Blue', '009BDE']],
    default: 'C9920E'
  }
```

But, for ease of use, I would like to actually display the color itself as the value description, so that instead of the name as a string, the list would display a small square of the color described by the hex code.

In looking at the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select), I don't see any way to use anything other than a string value.  Is there a way to display the description using HTML/CSS, or am I limited to string values in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select elements used on the dialogs are normal HTML select elements.
In order to achieve what you want you'll have to use instead a HTML field in the dialog and then use in that HTML whatever HTML + CSS + Javascript that achieves the desired look.